# Dealing with ex-girlfriend suicide threat

Tags: relationships, online-interaction, suicide, iran

I recently broke up with her, and it wasn't very peaceful. I am sure that she was somehow trying to cheat me. After a day of silent treatment (we don't see each other a lot, we chat via Internet), I told her that I can NOT bear the thought and we need to separate at once.

Following my anger, I didn't read what she said and instantly deleted all her messages, blocked her on my social networks and ever since trying to forget her.

Yesterday, my friends told me that she somehow threatened to kill herself "if he (me) doesn't come back". It is obvious that if God-forbidden she ever does that, I'll be in deep trouble.

Here's the things I considered, which they don't work:

- **Calling her family.** Strictly impossible. The situation here (Iran) is way more complicated than you think it is.
- **Calling her friends.** She isn't very social and as far as I know, she doesn't have more than 1 or 2 close friends and I don't know them and I suppose they don't, either.
- **Talking to her.** No way, until I'm sure that she's serious about her decision.

What do I do now?

**About seeking professional considerations:**
I already tried to consider a psychologist, but he refuses to help unless he can talk to my ex, which is not possible at this moment. She doesn't answer to strangers' messages.

P.S.: English is not my first language, there might be mistakes in this text. I hope you forgive my mistakes :-).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this appears to be a "seek professional help" situation. While we would like to help, some situations call for the specific expertise of doctors, therapists, lawyers, or law enforcement.

Comment: I'd agree that "seek professional help" should be the first course of action,but if that's not available, I think that there are some valuable skills to be learned here.  So I'm upvoting.

Comment: OP: if this can be reworded to something along the line of "I know to seek professional help.  How do I react to threats of suicide without being manipulated?", there be a good reason to reopen this question.

Answer (score 6):

This does not at all feel like an interpersonal question but as I sympathize with your sense of urgency and the delicacy of the situation I will toss in some advice.

The following was grabbed from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_suicide_crisis_lines):

> Iran Organization of Well Being (http://moshaver.behzisti.ir/page.aspx?id=1480) has provided the free and governmental hotline, 1480, by which the specialists give different types of consultations for a variety of problems such as marriage, family, youths and children, suicide,etc. to those in need. this hotline is open from 6 am till 9 pm everyday and its services are reached from all provinces of Iran.

I have no experience on how they conduct things but the Wikipedia summary makes it look promising, seeking expertise and assistance from there definitely seems like your best bet right now.

A good solution in general for this type of situation is to find the right resources with more experience than yourself to utilize (helplines, professionals, institutions, etc) especially when you fear that someone's life is concerned. No doubt you will get much better help from one of these located in your country than you ever could from us here.

Best of luck.